# How exactly does C++ runtime use the vptr to choose the right function.Who takes care of this?

Tags: c++

I am confused how vptr resolves virtual function call at run time if there are more virtual functions in a class. Who takes care of that. And who creates vtable . is it compiler?

Comment: What is `vptr`?

Comment: Yes, the compiler is responsible for implementing the language rules. The rules say how member function calls are to be dispatched. So the compiler has to generate code that effects those dispatch rules.

Answer (score 5):

Consider code something like this:

```
class A {
    int x;
public:
    virtual void foo() { std::cout << "base::foo()\n"; }
    virtual void bar() = 0;
    virtual ~A() {}
};

class B : public A {
    int y;
public: 
    virtual void bar() { std::cout << "Derived::bar()"; }
    virtual void baz() { std::cout << "Added function"; }
};

int main() { 
    A a;
    B b;
}
```

This is going to result in a layout something on this general order:

[image]

So, each object contains its own copy of the object's data, which is an amalgamation of all the data defined in that class and all its base classes. When it contains at least one virtual function, it has a vtable pointer. That points to a table somewhere in the generated code. That table, in turn, contains pointers to the virtual functions for the class. The key to this working is that (for virtual functions that are common between them) the base class and derived class store those pointers at the same offsets in the vtable. When you invoke a virtual function, the compiler generates code to "chase" the vtable pointer, then invoke the function at the right offset in the vtable.

Although it's not shown directly here, when each member function (virtual or otherwise) is called, the address of the variable is typically passed as a hidden parameter that's named `this` inside the function. References to members can use `this` implicitly (so an assignment like `somember=a;` is really equivalent to `this->somemember = a;`).

Note: this is depicting how things are *typically* done--at least in theory, an implementation is free to do things entirely differently, as long as what it does meets the requirements in the standard. That said, every implementation of which I'm aware works *fairly* similarly.